# Jenkins change log timestamp to 24 hour format

Tags: logging, jenkins

By default, Jenkins' main log contains timestamps like the following:

```
Sep 26, 2014 7:03:00 PM hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner run
INFO: SCM changes detected in main-web-flow. Triggering  #613
```

I would prefer the time to be in 24-hour format, which is more readable (especially as my Jenkins Master is in a different time zone to myself).  How/Where do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property to the jvm running jenkins, which is using java.util.loggin, like in (for YYYY-mm-dd):

```
java -Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="[%1$Tf] %4$s: %2$s - %5$s %6$s%n"
```

You can find documentation on how to build the format string in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax); while `1$`, `2$`,... are placeholders for the values passed in to the logger.